# error C2660: 'PyDict_GetItem': function does not take 1 arguments see declaration of 'PyDict_GetItem' ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed

Tags: python, c++, cmake, pytorch

I am running into an issue when trying to build pytorch-1.12.1 from source. I have search the web for a solution but cannot find one. I am not familiar with C++ so this stuff can become quite confusing to me.
Here are some specs of my system:
(CUDNN 8.9.4,CUDA 11.4,GPU Arch 86, Visual Studio 16 2019, cmake 3.27.1, Windows 10, 3080 GPU)
and these are the commands I run where I run into an error:

```
git clone --branch v1.12.1 https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch.git pytorch-1.12.1
cd pytorch-1.12.1
git submodule sync
git submodule deinit -f .
git submodule update --init --recursive
pip install -r requirements.txt
python setup.py build
```

after building for some time I start to get errors and end up with this in my terminal:

```
(haloapi) C:\pytorch-1.12.1>python setup.py build
Building wheel torch-1.12.0a0+git664058f
-- Building version 1.12.0a0+git664058f
cmake --build . --target install --config Release
[2/153] Building CXX object caffe2\torch\CMakeFile...src\autograd\generated\python_return_types.cpp.obj
FAILED: caffe2/torch/CMakeFiles/torch_python.dir/csrc/autograd/generated/python_return_types.cpp.obj
C:\PROGRA~2\MICROS~2\2019\COMMUN~1\VC\Tools\MSVC\1429~1.301\bin\Hostx64\x64\cl.exe  /nologo /TP -DAT_PER_OPERATOR_HEADERS -DBUILDING_TESTS -DFMT_HEADER_ONLY=1 -DMINIZ_DISABLE_ZIP_READER_CRC32_CHECKS -DONNXIFI_ENABLE_EXT=1 -DONNX_ML=1 -DONNX_NAMESPACE=onnx_torch -DTHP_BUILD_MAIN_LIB -DUSE_CUDA -DUSE_CUDNN -DUSE_EXTERNAL_MZCRC -DUSE_NUMPY -DWIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN -D_CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE=1 -Dtorch_python_EXPORTS -IC:\pytorch-1.12.1\build\aten\src -IC:\pytorch-1.12.1\aten\src -IC:\pytorch-1.12.1\build -IC:\pytorch-1.12.1 -IC:\pytorch-1.12.1\cmake\..\third_party\benchmark\include -IC:\pytorch-1.12.1\cmake\..\third_party\cudnn_frontend\include -IC:\pytorch-1.12.1\third_party\onnx -IC:\pytorch-1.12.1\build\third_party\onnx -IC:\pytorch-1.12.1\third_party\foxi -IC:\pytorch-1.12.1\build\third_party\foxi -IC:\pytorch-1.12.1\torch\.. -IC:\pytorch-1.12.1\torch\..\aten\src -IC:\pytorch-1.12.1\torch\..\aten\src\TH -IC:\pytorch-1.12.1\build\caffe2\aten\src -IC:\pytorch-1.12.1\build\third_party -IC:\pytorch-1.12.1\torch\..\third_party\valgrind-headers -IC:\pytorch-1.12.1\torch\..\third_party\gloo -IC:\pytorch-1.12.1\torch\..\third_party\onnx -IC:\pytorch-1.12.1\torch\..\third_party\flatbuffers\include -IC:\pytorch-1.12.1\torch\csrc -IC:\pytorch-1.12.1\torch\csrc\api\include -IC:\pytorch-1.12.1\torch\lib -IC:\pytorch-1.12.1\torch\lib\libshm_windows -IC:\pytorch-1.12.1\torch\csrc\distributed -IC:\pytorch-1.12.1\torch\csrc\api -IC:\pytorch-1.12.1\c10\.. -IC:\pytorch-1.12.1\c10\cuda\..\.. -IC:\pytorch-1.12.1\third_party\fmt\include -external:IC:\pytorch-1.12.1\cmake\..\third_party\googletest\googlemock\include -external:IC:\pytorch-1.12.1\cmake\..\third_party\googletest\googletest\include -external:IC:\pytorch-1.12.1\third_party\protobuf\src -external:IC:\pytorch-1.12.1\third_party\XNNPACK\include -external:IC:\pytorch-1.12.1\cmake\..\third_party\eigen -external:I"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.4\include" -external:IC:\pytorch-1.12.1\third_party\ideep\mkl-dnn\third_party\oneDNN\include -external:IC:\pytorch-1.12.1\third_party\ideep\include -external:IC:\Anaconda3\envs\haloapi\include -external:IC:\Anaconda3\envs\haloapi\Lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include -external:I"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NvToolsExt\include" -external:IC:\pytorch-1.12.1\cmake\..\third_party\pybind11\include -external:W0 /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /GR /EHsc /w /bigobj -DUSE_PTHREADPOOL -openmp:experimental -DNDEBUG -DUSE_KINETO -DLIBKINETO_NOCUPTI -DUSE_FBGEMM -DUSE_XNNPACK -DSYMBOLICATE_MOBILE_DEBUG_HANDLE -DEDGE_PROFILER_USE_KINETO -DHAVE_AVX512_CPU_DEFINITION -DHAVE_AVX2_CPU_DEFINITION /MD /O2 /Ob2 /DNDEBUG /w /bigobj -DNDEBUG -std:c++14 -DTH_HAVE_THREAD /EHsc /DNOMINMAX /wd4267 /wd4251 /wd4522 /wd4838 /wd4305 /wd4244 /wd4190 /wd4101 /wd4996 /wd4275 /bigobj /showIncludes /Focaffe2\torch\CMakeFiles\torch_python.dir\csrc\autograd\generated\python_return_types.cpp.obj /Fdcaffe2\torch\CMakeFiles\torch_python.dir\ /FS -c C:\pytorch-1.12.1\torch\csrc\autograd\generated\python_return_types.cpp
C:\pytorch-1.12.1\third_party\pybind11\include\pybind11\cast.h(446): error C2027: use of undefined type '_frame'
C:\Anaconda3\envs\haloapi\include\pytypedefs.h(22): note: see declaration of '_frame'
C:\pytorch-1.12.1\third_party\pybind11\include\pybind11\cast.h(448): error C2027: use of undefined type '_frame'
C:\Anaconda3\envs\haloapi\include\pytypedefs.h(22): note: see declaration of '_frame'
C:\pytorch-1.12.1\third_party\pybind11\include\pybind11\cast.h(449): error C2027: use of undefined type '_frame'
C:\Anaconda3\envs\haloapi\include\pytypedefs.h(22): note: see declaration of '_frame'
C:\pytorch-1.12.1\cmake\..\third_party\pybind11\include\pybind11/pybind11.h(2291): error C2039: 'frame': is not a member of '_ts'
C:\Anaconda3\envs\haloapi\include\cpython/pystate.h(82): note: see declaration of '_ts'
C:\pytorch-1.12.1\cmake\..\third_party\pybind11\include\pybind11/pybind11.h(2292): error C2027: use of undefined type '_frame'
C:\Anaconda3\envs\haloapi\include\pytypedefs.h(22): note: see declaration of '_frame'
C:\pytorch-1.12.1\cmake\..\third_party\pybind11\include\pybind11/pybind11.h(2293): error C2027: use of undefined type '_frame'
C:\Anaconda3\envs\haloapi\include\pytypedefs.h(22): note: see declaration of '_frame'
C:\pytorch-1.12.1\cmake\..\third_party\pybind11\include\pybind11/pybind11.h(2296): error C2027: use of undefined type '_frame'
C:\Anaconda3\envs\haloapi\include\pytypedefs.h(22): note: see declaration of '_frame'
C:\pytorch-1.12.1\cmake\..\third_party\pybind11\include\pybind11/pybind11.h(2295): error C2660: 'PyDict_GetItem': function does not take 1 arguments
C:\Anaconda3\envs\haloapi\include\dictobject.h(22): note: see declaration of 'PyDict_GetItem'


...
...
...
...


C:\Anaconda3\envs\haloapi\include\pytypedefs.h(22): note: see declaration of '_frame'
C:\pytorch-1.12.1\cmake\..\third_party\pybind11\include\pybind11/pybind11.h(2295): error C2660: 'PyDict_GetItem': function does not take 1 arguments
C:\Anaconda3\envs\haloapi\include\dictobject.h(22): note: see declaration of 'PyDict_GetItem'
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

The above code snippet just shows the errors as everything else is already built. When I run the build command for the first time here is some of the output that I think should provide some helpful debugging information:

```
(haloapi) C:\pytorch-1.12.1>python setup.py build

--
-- ******** Summary ********
-- General:
--   CMake version         : 3.27.5
--   CMake command         : C:/Anaconda3/envs/haloapi/Lib/site-packages/cmake/data/bin/cmake.exe
--   System                : Windows
--   C++ compiler          : C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.29.30133/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe
--   C++ compiler id       : MSVC
--   C++ compiler version  : 19.29.30152.0
--   Using ccache if found : OFF
--   CXX flags             : /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /GR /EHsc /w /bigobj -DUSE_PTHREADPOOL -openmp:experimental -DNDEBUG -DUSE_KINETO -DLIBKINETO_NOCUPTI -DUSE_FBGEMM -DUSE_XNNPACK -DSYMBOLICATE_MOBILE_DEBUG_HANDLE -DEDGE_PROFILER_USE_KINETO
--   Build type            : Release
--   Compile definitions   : WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN;ONNX_ML=1;ONNXIFI_ENABLE_EXT=1;ONNX_NAMESPACE=onnx_torch;_CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE=1;USE_EXTERNAL_MZCRC;MINIZ_DISABLE_ZIP_READER_CRC32_CHECKS
--   CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH     : C:\Anaconda3\envs\haloapi\Lib\site-packages;C:/Program Files/NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit/CUDA/v11.4
--   CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX  : C:/pytorch-1.12.1/torch
--   USE_GOLD_LINKER       : OFF
--
--   TORCH_VERSION         : 1.12.0
--   CAFFE2_VERSION        : 1.12.0
--   BUILD_CAFFE2          : OFF
--   BUILD_CAFFE2_OPS      : OFF
--   BUILD_CAFFE2_MOBILE   : OFF
--   BUILD_STATIC_RUNTIME_BENCHMARK: OFF
--   BUILD_TENSOREXPR_BENCHMARK: OFF
--   BUILD_NVFUSER_BENCHMARK: ON
--   BUILD_BINARY          : OFF
--   BUILD_CUSTOM_PROTOBUF : ON
--     Link local protobuf : ON
--   BUILD_DOCS            : OFF
--   BUILD_PYTHON          : True
--     Python version      : 3.11
--     Python executable   : C:/Anaconda3/envs/haloapi/python.exe
--     Pythonlibs version  : 3.11.0
--     Python library      : C:/Anaconda3/envs/haloapi/libs/python311.lib
--     Python includes     : C:/Anaconda3/envs/haloapi/include
--     Python site-packages: Lib/site-packages
--   BUILD_SHARED_LIBS     : ON
--   CAFFE2_USE_MSVC_STATIC_RUNTIME     : OFF
--   BUILD_TEST            : True
--   BUILD_JNI             : OFF
--   BUILD_MOBILE_AUTOGRAD : OFF
--   BUILD_LITE_INTERPRETER: OFF
--   INTERN_BUILD_MOBILE   :
--   USE_BLAS              : 0
--   USE_LAPACK            : 0
--   USE_ASAN              : OFF
--   USE_CPP_CODE_COVERAGE : OFF
--   USE_CUDA              : ON
--     Split CUDA          : OFF
--     CUDA static link    : OFF
--     USE_CUDNN           : ON
--     USE_EXPERIMENTAL_CUDNN_V8_API: ON
--     CUDA version        : 11.4
--     cuDNN version       : 8.9.4
--     CUDA root directory : C:/Program Files/NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit/CUDA/v11.4
--     CUDA library        : C:/Program Files/NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit/CUDA/v11.4/lib/x64/cuda.lib
--     cudart library      : C:/Program Files/NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit/CUDA/v11.4/lib/x64/cudart_static.lib
--     cublas library      : C:/Program Files/NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit/CUDA/v11.4/lib/x64/cublas.lib
--     cufft library       : C:/Program Files/NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit/CUDA/v11.4/lib/x64/cufft.lib
--     curand library      : C:/Program Files/NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit/CUDA/v11.4/lib/x64/curand.lib
--     cuDNN library       : C:/Program Files/NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit/CUDA/v11.4/lib/x64/cudnn.lib
--     nvrtc               : C:/Program Files/NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit/CUDA/v11.4/lib/x64/nvrtc.lib
--     CUDA include path   : C:/Program Files/NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit/CUDA/v11.4/include
--     NVCC executable     : C:/Program Files/NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit/CUDA/v11.4/bin/nvcc.exe
--     CUDA compiler       : C:/Program Files/NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit/CUDA/v11.4/bin/nvcc.exe
--     CUDA flags          :  -Xcompiler /w -w -Xfatbin -compress-all -DONNX_NAMESPACE=onnx_torch --use-local-env -gencode arch=compute_86,code=sm_86 -Xcudafe --diag_suppress=cc_clobber_ignored,--diag_suppress=integer_sign_change,--diag_suppress=useless_using_declaration,--diag_suppress=set_but_not_used,--diag_suppress=field_without_dll_interface,--diag_suppress=base_class_has_different_dll_interface,--diag_suppress=dll_interface_conflict_none_assumed,--diag_suppress=dll_interface_conflict_dllexport_assumed,--diag_suppress=implicit_return_from_non_void_function,--diag_suppress=unsigned_compare_with_zero,--diag_suppress=declared_but_not_referenced,--diag_suppress=bad_friend_decl --Werror cross-execution-space-call --no-host-device-move-forward --expt-relaxed-constexpr --expt-extended-lambda  -Xcompiler=/wd4819,/wd4503,/wd4190,/wd4244,/wd4251,/wd4275,/wd4522 -Wno-deprecated-gpu-targets --expt-extended-lambda -DCUDA_HAS_FP16=1 -D__CUDA_NO_HALF_OPERATORS__ -D__CUDA_NO_HALF_CONVERSIONS__ -D__CUDA_NO_HALF2_OPERATORS__ -D__CUDA_NO_BFLOAT16_CONVERSIONS__
--     CUDA host compiler  :
--     CUDA --device-c     : OFF
--     USE_TENSORRT        : OFF
--   USE_ROCM              : OFF
--   USE_EIGEN_FOR_BLAS    : ON
--   USE_FBGEMM            : ON
--     USE_FAKELOWP          : OFF
--   USE_KINETO            : ON
--   USE_FFMPEG            : OFF
--   USE_GFLAGS            : OFF
--   USE_GLOG              : OFF
--   USE_LEVELDB           : OFF
--   USE_LITE_PROTO        : OFF
--   USE_LMDB              : OFF
--   USE_METAL             : OFF
--   USE_PYTORCH_METAL     : OFF
--   USE_PYTORCH_METAL_EXPORT     : OFF
--   USE_MPS               : OFF
--   USE_FFTW              : OFF
--   USE_MKL               : OFF
--   USE_MKLDNN            : ON
--   USE_NCCL              : OFF
--   USE_NNPACK            : OFF
--   USE_NUMPY             : ON
--   USE_OBSERVERS         : ON
--   USE_OPENCL            : OFF
--   USE_OPENCV            : OFF
--   USE_OPENMP            : ON
--   USE_TBB               : OFF
--   USE_VULKAN            : OFF
--   USE_PROF              : OFF
--   USE_QNNPACK           : OFF
--   USE_PYTORCH_QNNPACK   : OFF
--   USE_XNNPACK           : ON
--   USE_REDIS             : OFF
--   USE_ROCKSDB           : OFF
--   USE_ZMQ               : OFF
--   USE_DISTRIBUTED       : OFF
--   USE_DEPLOY           : OFF
--   Public Dependencies  : caffe2::Threads
--   Private Dependencies : pthreadpool;cpuinfo;XNNPACK;fbgemm;fp16;foxi_loader;fmt::fmt-header-only;kineto
--   USE_COREML_DELEGATE     : OFF
--   BUILD_LAZY_TS_BACKEND   : ON
-- Configuring done (177.4s)
-- Generating done (2.7s)
-- Build files have been written to: C:/pytorch-1.12.1/build
cmake --build . --target install --config Release
```

Any help or recommendations on what I should try or due to fix this issue is appreciated as I am totally stuck now. Code from the cast.h file:

```
PYBIND11_NOINLINE inline std::string error_string() {
    if (!PyErr_Occurred()) {
        PyErr_SetString(PyExc_RuntimeError, "Unknown internal error occurred");
        return "Unknown internal error occurred";
    }

    error_scope scope; // Preserve error state

    std::string errorString;
    if (scope.type) {
        errorString += handle(scope.type).attr("__name__").cast<std::string>();
        errorString += ": ";
    }
    if (scope.value)
        errorString += (std::string) str(scope.value);

    PyErr_NormalizeException(&scope.type, &scope.value, &scope.trace);

#if PY_MAJOR_VERSION >= 3
    if (scope.trace != nullptr)
        PyException_SetTraceback(scope.value, scope.trace);
#endif

#if !defined(PYPY_VERSION)
    if (scope.trace) {
        auto *trace = (PyTracebackObject *) scope.trace;

        /* Get the deepest trace possible */
        while (trace->tb_next)
            trace = trace->tb_next;

        PyFrameObject *frame = trace->tb_frame;
        errorString += "\n\nAt:\n";
        while (frame) {
            int lineno = PyFrame_GetLineNumber(frame);
            errorString +=
                "  " + handle(frame->f_code->co_filename).cast<std::string>() +
                "(" + std::to_string(lineno) + "): " +
                handle(frame->f_code->co_name).cast<std::string>() + "\n";
            frame = frame->f_back;
        }
    }
#endif

    return errorString;
```

Comment: I would solve the initial errors first. A later error about wrong number of arguments can often depend on earlier errors making one parameter invalid.

Comment: The error shown is the first error. but the script continues for a while, outputting similar errors until it stops.

Comment: The first error seems to be "use of undefined type '_frame'". I would try to sort that out first, and then perhaps see that a *properly defined* type makes the missing argument also defined.

Comment: Thank you for the input, I took a look at the code in the cast.h file referenced in the error line but it is c++ and I cannot understand what the function is doing. I did a search for "_frame" and it is not in the document but "frame" is.